# Error:java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 app

Tags: android, android-studio

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\a0924\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build_tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 app.

When i run my app this error will occur and all my R references in the program cannot be resolved.

Help me it has been a few days!!!

Comment: It looks like your Build Tools may be corrupted. Try to reinstall it from inside Android Studio (remove it and then install it again).

Comment: You are terrific!!! i just did what you said and i fixed it, but how do you know my Build Tools is corrupted??

Comment: I saw it in the path `\build_tools`. And `aapt.exe` is a build tool. :) Glad I helped.

Comment: Oh, I see~Thank u!!

Answer (score 2):

I once have same problem. Problem is in "build_tools" folder So, solved it by change the "Android SDK Build Tool" version 18.0.2 to 18.0.1 . Upgrade or downgrade "Android SDK Build Tool" version may solve it as me.

[File->Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lLXI.jpg)

[image]