# Compiled GoggleTest on AndroidStudio gives not a Win32 application error when given a arm64 phone

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, googletest, arm64

My compiled google tests are giving me the following error:

```
Error running test executable.

    Path: 'C:/repository/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/6t1p3yv6/obj/arm64-v8a/UnitTest'
    Result: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    Output:
```

This of course is true. I am providing it a Samsung arm64 device to build for and run the tests on for Android Studio. My problem is that it is obviously trying to run the resulting tests on Windows, which will not work.

The tests are in the AndroidTest directory as well.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt building my c++ files for my jni interface. File and program names have been changed but the structure is the same.

```
project(ncnncomputervision)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opencv-mobile-4.5.4-android/sdk/native/jni)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc)

set(ncnn_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ncnn-20230223-android-vulkan/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/cmake/ncnn)
find_package(ncnn REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libzmq/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libzmq/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib)

add_library(
        ncnncomputervision SHARED
        cvncnn.cpp
        cv.cpp
        cv_ncnn.cpp
        mat_output.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(ncnncomputervision 
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        camera2ndk
        mediandk
        ncnn
        zmq
)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
set(Test_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../androidTest/cpp/jni)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
        UnitTest
        ${Test_DIR}/unittest.cpp
        cv_ncnn.cpp
        cv.cpp
        mat_output.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
        UnitTest
        GTest::gtest_main
        GTest::gmock_main
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ncnn
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(UnitTest)
```

Here's an exerpt from the relevant portions of my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    ndkVersion "21.4.7075529"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.applictation"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionName getVersionName()
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "UnitTest"
                cppFlags ''
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version '3.22.1'
            path file('src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
        jniLibs {
            pickFirsts += ['**']
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing from my CMakeLists.txt or might be missing from my build.gradle that could cause it to want to run these on Windows rather than the phone?

Steps taken and searches done:

[Running unit test in golang error: %1 is not a valid win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921360/running-unit-test-in-golang-error-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)
Restarted PC as suggested by one of the answers, not solved.

[How do I resolve "%1 is not a valid Win32 application"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185042/how-do-i-resolve-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)
Not relevant as my path is not cluttered or messed up in Windows. I've looked at environment variables. This also has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

[Why the error? %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406593/why-the-error-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)
No answers here. Also I am not using python code, so unlikely to be related.

[Error:java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934040/errorjava-io-ioexception-createprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-app)
Uninstalled and reinstalled SDK did not help.

[Cannot run program "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505947/cannot-run-program-c-users-admin-appdata-local-android-sdk-platform-tools-adb)
Offered same solution as above, just with more steps. Did not perform again.

[error when running a Flutter app on my device in Android Studio : "ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073456/error-when-running-a-flutter-app-on-my-device-in-android-studio-processexcept)
Invalidated and rebuilt caches. Should have the same effect. Rebuilding the project from scratch is a non-starter.

Edit: Recently learned the difference between the AndroidTest and normal Test directories, and clarified where the tests were located.

Added clarification on where C++ tests were located. May solve problems in the short term by moving tests to the Test folder, but some future tests may require the Android subsystem to run, which leaves this an open question.

Comment: Have you tried following this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448545/7623655

Comment: That was how I found the gradle code to add, but please note that the answer is 6 years old now, and the gradle version is 4 versions out of date. We are using gradle 7.5 now. I'm not sure how much of that even still applies. Also, most of the NDK instructions links are dead as that is not how it's done anymore on the android side. Those Android.mk files are autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

This is at least a partial answer to the question.

I discovered what caused Gradle to run the unit tests in the first place, but not why it chooses them to run them on the host OS rather than the phone. Omitting the following line in the CMakelists will prevent the execution of the unit test, allowing you to run the unit test at your convenience without breaking your build.

```
gtest_discover_tests(UnitTest)
```

I'm not choosing this as an answer due to the fact that this is only part of the solution, not the whole thing.